# What is the best way to use multiple controllers and models in Laravel

Tags: laravel, controller, request

I've a project with multiple controllers and models. For example, The table **products** have a "*child*" table ***(the detail of product)*** with name "producto_material".

In the frontend the user create a new product, but this product must have one detail at least. When the user press "Create product" the request goes with the product information (*products*) and detail info product (*producto_material*).

At moment I've the next structure:

- Controllers (ProductoController, ProductoMaterialController)
- Models (ProductoModel, ProductoMaterialModel)

I'll like that each controller take care of yours with own validation, but the request goes to the ProductController.

Web routes:

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductoController');
Route::get('duplicar/{param?}', 'ProductoExtController@duplicar');
Route::post('mostrarProductos', 'ProductoExtController@mostrarProductos');
Route::post('guardarValoresEditados', 'ProductoExtController@guardarValoresEditados');
Route::get('imprimirListadoPrecios', 'ProductoExtController@imprimirListadoPrecios');
Route::post('mostrarProductosStickers', 'ProductoExtController@mostrarProductosStickers');
Route::post('imprimirStickers','ProductoExtController@imprimirStickers');
```

Product Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Modelos\ProductsModel;
use App\Modelos\ProductoMaterialModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use App\Http\Requests\ProductoValidationRules;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class ProductoController extends Controller
{

    protected $proMaterialesProducto;

    public function __construct(ProductoMaterialController $pMaterialesProducto)
    {
        $this->proMaterialesProducto = $pMaterialesProducto;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        if (\Gate::allows('isAdmin') || \Gate::allows('isUser')){
            return ProductsModel::latest()
                        ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
                        ->paginate(10);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(ProductoValidationRules $request)
    {   
        $vIntIdProducto = 0;

        try {
            $validated = $request->validated();

            DB::beginTransaction();

            $vIntIdProducto = ProductsModel::insertGetId([
                'f014_nombre' => $request['nombre'],
                'f014_precio_basico'=> $request['vlrBasico'],
                'f014_precio_premium' => $request['vlrPelete'],
                'f014_categoria_id'  => $request['categoria'],            
                'f014_id_coleccion'=> $request['coleccion'],
                'created_at'=> Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),     
                'f014_creado_por'=> Auth::id(),
            ]);

            foreach (Arr::get($request,'colores') as $key => $color) {
                ProductoMaterialModel::insert([
                    'f019_producto_id' => $vIntIdProducto,
                    'f019_crosta_id'=> Arr::get($color,'crosta.valor'),
                    'f019_id_folia1' => Arr::get($color,'folia1.valor'),
                    'f019_id_folia2'  => Arr::get($color,'folia2.valor'),          
                    'f019_id_folia3'=> Arr::get($color,'folia3.valor'),
                    'f019_color'=> Arr::get($color,'color'),
                    'f019_creado_por'=> Auth::id(),
                ]);
            }

            DB::commit();

            return response()
            ->json(['status' => true]);

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            DB::rollBack();
            return response()
            ->json([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'Fallo la creación del producto '.$th->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $vProductsModel = ProductsModel::with(
                            'MaterialesCombinaciones.Crostas',
                            'MaterialesCombinaciones.Folia1',
                            'MaterialesCombinaciones.Folia2',
                            'MaterialesCombinaciones.Folia3'
                        )
                        ->where('f014_id',$id)
                        ->get();

        return response()
                ->json($vProductsModel);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $vProductos = null;

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            $vProductos = ProductsModel::find($id);
            $vProductos->f014_precio_basico = $request['vlrBasico'];
            $vProductos->f014_precio_premium = $request['vlrPelete'];
            $vProductos->f014_modificado_por = Auth::id();

            $vProductos->save();

            foreach (Arr::get($request,'colores') as $key => $color) {
                ProductoMaterialModel::updateOrCreate(
                    [
                        'f019_producto_id' => $id, 
                        'f019_crosta_id' => Arr::get($color,'crosta.valor'),
                        'f019_color'=>Arr::get($color,'color')
                    ],
                    [
                        'f019_id_folia1' => Arr::get($color,'folia1.valor'),
                        'f019_id_folia2' =>  Arr::get($color,'folia2.valor'),
                        'f019_modificado_por'=>Auth::id()
                    ]
                );
            }


            DB::commit();
            return response()
            ->json(['status' => true]);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {

            DB::rollBack();
            return response()
            ->json([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'Fallo la actualización del producto '.$th->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        ProductsModel::destroy($id);
    }
}
```

I think this is wrong:

```
 $vIntIdProducto = ProductsModel::insertGetId([
                'f014_nombre' => $request['nombre'],
                'f014_precio_basico'=> $request['vlrBasico'],
                'f014_precio_premium' => $request['vlrPelete'],
                'f014_categoria_id'  => $request['categoria'],            
                'f014_id_coleccion'=> $request['coleccion'],
                'created_at'=> Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),     
                'f014_creado_por'=> Auth::id(),
            ]);

            foreach (Arr::get($request,'colores') as $key => $color) {
                ProductoMaterialModel::insert([
                    'f019_producto_id' => $vIntIdProducto,
                    'f019_crosta_id'=> Arr::get($color,'crosta.valor'),
                    'f019_id_folia1' => Arr::get($color,'folia1.valor'),
                    'f019_id_folia2'  => Arr::get($color,'folia2.valor'),          
                    'f019_id_folia3'=> Arr::get($color,'folia3.valor'),
                    'f019_color'=> Arr::get($color,'color'),
                    'f019_creado_por'=> Auth::id(),
                ]);
            }
```

Comment: If a user CAN'T create 'ProductoMaterial' without the 'Producto' then you don't need the ProductoMaterialController... You just make a relationship Producto->hasMany(ProductoMaterial::class) and when you store the Producto you create the ProductoMaterial with it

Comment: There is nothing wrong with creating a Parent + Children records in the same controllers. I would say this should be the right way. The only thing is, if you're using InnoDB Engine or database that support transaction, then you should use your inserts in DB transaction to ensure parent does not save whitout a child. Use `\DB::beginTransaction();` before inserts, `\DB::commit();` after, and `\DB::rollback();` on catching exception.